# Animating a square on a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

I have a panel on a form which creates the topology of a network for routing packets. I am able to draw the topology on the panel. But, now I want small squares to move from one point to the destination on a button click. How can I do this on a panel? Nothing happens when I click on the button. I will appreciate if anyone could help me. This is part of my code:

```cpp
public Form1()
{            
     InitializeComponent();

     this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint 
          | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint
          | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);

    //Initialize the point to start in the top left corner
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint
          | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint
          | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);

    //Initialize the point to start in the top left corner
    mPoint = new Point(mRect.Location.X, mRect.Location.X);

    //Set up the function to call when the timer fires
    TimerCallback timercb = new TimerCallback(TimerCB);

    //Set up the timer to fire at the set animation rate
    mTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(timercb,
        null, ANIMATION_RATE, ANIMATION_RATE);    
}

private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if(sendbut) {
        Graphics dc = panel2.CreateGraphics();
        //Fill the background of the client area
        dc.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Control, this.ClientRectangle);

        //Draw the big rectangle track
        dc.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, mRect);

        //Clone the point
        Point p = new Point(mPoint.X, mPoint.Y);

        //Offset it by half the width and height of the desired rectangle
        p.Offset(-(RECT_WIDTH / 2), -(RECT_HEIGHT / 2));

        //Draw the little moving rectangle
        dc.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 
            new Rectangle(p, new Size(RECT_WIDTH, RECT_HEIGHT)));
    }
}

protected void TimerCB(object o)
{
    //Move the rectangle
    MovePoint();

    //Redraw the form
    Invalidate();
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    sendbutt = true;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why it's not working with you, but try to use `e.Graphics` instead of `panel2.CreateGraphics()`; maybe that's part of the issue.

Comment: Yes, that's wrong.  Also "sendbutt" vs "sendbut".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `panel2_Paint`is a handler for the `panel2.Paint` event, that method will be called *after* paint has occurred. What you want to do instead is, create a custom control that inherits from Panel and override the OnPaint method. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx).